# Meson absolute path from include_directories

Tags: meson-build

In Meson, is it possible to get a string absolute path from an object created by a call to `include_directories`?

My use case:

```py
    include_dirs = include_directories('include')
    lib = library(
        'mylib',
        source_files,
        include_directories: include_dirs
    )
    run_target('analyze',
        command: ['static_analysis',
            source_files,
            '-I', include_dirs.to_abs_path(),
        ]
    )
```

`include_dirs.to_abs_path()` does not exist, but I wonder if something similar is possible. Alternatively, `files()` exists(as used for `source_files` here); is there a `directories()`?

Answer (score 6):

You probably found out how to achieve this by now, but if anyone is looking for the same thing, you can get the root directory by calling

```
dir_base = meson.current_source_dir()
```

This returns the directory of the current meson build file.
Then you could construct the include path by doing

```
dir_include = join_paths(dir_base, 'include')
```